# TiDB as metastore for hive

Tags: hive, hive-metastore, tidb

Is somebody using TiDB as metastore for hive installation?
Looking for experience and testimonials as we are evaluating it to solve our current metastore bottleneck while using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This was published a while ago: https://www.pingcap.com/blog/create-scale-out-hive-cluster-with-distributed-mysql-compatible-database/

A search also found this: https://dzone.com/articles/cluster-diagnostics-troubleshoot-cluster-issues-us-2

I think TiDB can provide high availability, online upgrades and scalability which would all be good for Hive.

Disclaimer: I'm working for PingCAP, the company behind TiDB.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I did went through these docs and found it fascinating.
Can you share some companies if you know who are using TiDB with hive?